# SDL2_mixer SDL_AudioStreamFlush could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c, dll, mingw, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I tried to make a sound in sdl 2, but when i compiled this line:

`Mix_OpenAudio( 44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048 );`

my exe told me that `SDL_AudioStreamFlush could not be located in the dynamic link library SDL2_mixer.dll` (there was also path to the dll).

Before asking I reinstalled everything and there was the same error.

I used SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.2-mingw SDL2_image-devel-2.0.1-mingw and SDL2-devel-2.0.6-mingw.

Compiled with this flags:`-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer`

Please someone who know SDL help!

P.S. sorry for bad english

Comment: Is this a _compiletime_ or a _runtime_ error?

Comment: runtime error ...

Comment: Then it looks like the compiler uses another variant of the library than the dynamic linker at runtime...

Comment: What can i do with this?

Comment: SDL 2.0.6 or later should have said symbol. Have you updated dll too in addition to `.dll.a`? Where is it placed? You can use dependency walker to check which dll will be loaded.

Comment: I just extracted all the stuff in SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.2-mingw SDL2_image-devel-2.0.1-mingw and SDL2-devel-2.0.6-mingw archives into one floder and put -IC and -LC. I do not know where I store `.dll.a` files

Comment: @MaximZhuchkov fine, but what about `SDL2.dll` itself? It should be reachable during execution, so in your executable's directory, or one of system directories (e.g. system32). If you haven't done that and one of system paths contains `SDL2.dll`, it will be loaded, which is very likely to be earlier than 2.0.6. That is exactly the reason I recommended dependency walker or something equivalent.

Comment: @keltar all dlls in the same directory with exe file. I moved all dll files into system32 and it seems to be good...

Comment: @keltar aaand the same error...

Comment: @MaximZhuchkov can reproduce on 64bit windows with mingw. Kind of surprised. It is fine with SDL 2.0.7 though.